# TableView not getting hidden in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, autocomplete

I m fairly new to objective-C and implementing the concept of autocomplete feature for a UItextField.I can do it appropriately .but when I select a particular cell then that cell's text should be displayed in UITextField and correspondingly tableView must be hidden.But Im unable to hide a UITableView after selecting a cell..Where I m going wrong?

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {


    NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://179.87.89.90/services/Service.svc/GetCities/?p=%@&k=%@",substring,txtId.text];     
    NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];  
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
    currentHTMLElement=@"3";
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr2);



    if([arr2 count]!=0)
    {
        self.autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(88, 447, 200, 120) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
        autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
        autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        // autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;  
        [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
        [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
            for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
            {
                NSString *curString = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];

                NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];

                if (substringRange.location == 0) 
                    [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  

            }
      [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        autocompleteTableView.delegate=nil;
        autocompleteTableView.dataSource=nil;
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;  

    }

}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {



    if( textField == txtcity)
    {
     autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return autocompleteUrls.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [autocompleteUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    txtcity.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
    [self.autocompleteTableView setHidden:YES];    
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        txtcity.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
        autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;

    }
```

How can I hide autocompleteTableView after selecting  a row ?
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: intead of this `autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;` try `tableView.hidden=YES;`

Comment: gone for it.still not getting

Comment: i think you have problem in some other place..... `autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;` and `tableView.hidden=YES;` are working fine

Comment: edited my code ..can u please have a look and rectify my mistake ..

Comment: it is my array response which i retrieved from that url

Comment: but now when i select a cell then tableview is disappeared but selected cells text is not displayed in UITextField.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { is not getting called ...What elz should I modify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the if condition, when the `if` is evaluated true then again the `autocompleteTableView` is again allocated and added to self.view. It'll be placed over the previous tableView and youare losing the reference of previous tableView. If you call `autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES`. Last added `tableView` will be hidden. But previously added tableViews will be there.

Just change the if block like:

```
if([arr2 count]!=0)
{
    self.autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(autocompleteTableView)
         [autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperView];
    autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(88, 447, 200, 120) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    // autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;  
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
        for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
        {
            NSString *curString = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];

            NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];

            if (substringRange.location == 0) 
                [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  

        }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: but now when i select a cell then tableview is disappeared but selected cells text is not displayed in UITextField.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { is not getting called ...What elz should I modify ?

Comment: @arizah: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is working, else it won't hide the tableView.

Comment: k got it..Thanks a lot.I was struggling my head for this..Thank u once again

Answer (score 0):

@Arizah - please try making a fresh app to test the UItableview & UItextField delegate methods. It might be that somewhere --

```
autocompleteTableView.delegate=nil;
autocompleteTableView.dataSource=nil;
```

gets called due to which further no delegate method like :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

WILL NOT BE CALLED. TRY AVOIDING THIS CODE.

Also the statement: **`self.autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`**
is technically incorrect since a retain property needs no allocation. Instead you can use:

```
NSMutableArray *theArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.autocompleteUrls = theArray;
[theArray release];
```

Answer (score -2):

did you try:

```
[self.tableView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: @simone hear two answer as same as your is ther no new code ...in your answer

Comment: @nitin tableView si different to self.tableView if you have property